# Change logo letters on hover/mouseenter using lettering. On mouseleave change back to original word/letters

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve a logo name "Thrive." and on hover/mouseenter changes letters to just "T." And when mouseleave changes back to "Thrive."

If anyone can help will be great. This can be done with Jquery and CSS. Thank you.

I've tried to achieve with logo image .fadeToggle() using jQuery and it is toggling both logo images. It doesn't look great with image, that's why I need help with lettering instead and I don't how?

Code used with .fadeToggle() below.

```
<div class="logos">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php theme_prefix_the_custom_logo()?></a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img class="hide" src="https://www.example.com/foldername/t-logo.png"></a>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.logos').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img:last-child").fadeToggle(500);
    });
});
```

On mouse hover/enter change logo word/letters to a single letter only the first letter, and on mouse leave letters changes back to the full word again

Comment: You shoud try yourself and come back if you don't manage, showing your code and errors. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: You might like to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although, I've tried to achieve with logo image .fadeToggle() using jQuery and it is toggling the images. It doesn't look great with image, thats why I need help with lettering instead and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="logos">
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><span>T</span><span class="hideIt">hrive</span></a>
</div>

$(".logos").on("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).find(".hideIt").hide()
});

$(".logos").on("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).find(".hideIt").show()
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyddlywink/wrqg54ab/)

I'll let you figure out how to make the lettering look pretty

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#logo{
margin:0px auto;
}
.text::before { 
content: "Thrive";
}
#logo:hover .text::before{
content: "T";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="logo"><p class="text"></p></span>
</body>
</html>
```

code in jsfiddle : [change title letters](https://jsfiddle.net/aden1web/5woLpv7c)